# Errors when passing pointer to structs c++

Tags: c++, pointers, debugging, reference

I am a beginner in C++, so I'm sure the error is from my misunderstanding of pointers.

I was making a Poker game, where `card` is a struct with the `suit` and the `value`, and each player's hand is filled with cards, and the middle is filled with cards. I passed references of the arrays to a function by reference, but I think something is wrong with how I set up the pointers to the arrays.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
enum suit {hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs};
enum value {two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace};

struct card 
{
    value v;
    suit s;
};
static const int num_players = 4;

void get_winner(const card ** hands[num_players][2], const card * mid_cards[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << "Middle card " << i + 1 << ": " << * mid_cards[i][0] << ", " << * mid_cards[i][1] << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        std::cout << "Player " << i + 1 << "hand: " << * hands[i][0] << ", " << * hands[i][1] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    card hands[num_players][2];
    card mid_cards[5];
    // fill hands and mid_cards with card structs
    hands[0][0] = card {jack, hearts};
    hands[0][1] = card {nine, spades};
    hands[1][0] = card {ace, clubs};
    hands[1][1] = card {ace, hearts};
    hands[2][0] = card {three, diamonds};
    hands[2][1] = card {seven, spades};
    hands[3][0] = card {eight, diamonds};
    hands[3][1] = card {nine, clubs};
    mid_cards[0] = card {five, clubs};
    mid_cards[1] = card {king, hearts};
    mid_cards[2] = card {queen, spades};
    mid_cards[3] = card {two, clubs};
    mid_cards[4] = card {ace, hearts};
    get_winner(&hands, &mid_cards);
}
```

Here are the error messages:

```
main.cpp:17:51: error: indirection requires pointer operand
      ('const card' invalid)
  ...<< "Middle card " << i + 1 << ": " << * mid_cards[i][0] << ", " << * mid...
                                           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:17:80: error: indirection requires pointer operand
      ('const card' invalid)
  ...i + 1 << ": " << * mid_cards[i][0] << ", " << * mid_cards[i][1] << "\n";
                                                   ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:42:2: error: no matching function for call to 'get_winner'
        get_winner(&hands, &mid_cards);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'card (*)[4][2]' to 'const card **(*)[2]' for 1st argument
void get_winner(const card ** hands[num_players][2], const card * mid_cards[5])
     ^
3 errors generated.
```

Comment: Please explain, in your own words, what you expect the expression `* mid_cards[i][0]` to represent. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: Instead of the struct card, I was thinking of an array of two values, suit and value, of which I wanted to print the suit, and then the value, and the * is to get the value at a pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function's parameters, you are using the wrong syntax to accept the arrays by pointer.  And, you are declaring the wrong *element type* for the arrays (you claim `card*` pointers, but the arrays actual hold `card` objects instead).  And, your function is treating the `mid_cards` parameter like it is a pointer to a 2-dimentional array when the actual array in `main()` is 1-dimensional instead.

Also, you do not have an `operator<<` defined for your `card` struct, but you are trying to print `card` values to `cout`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

enum suit {hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs};
enum value {two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace};

struct card 
{
    value v;
    suit s;
};
static const int num_players = 4;

static const char* suits[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
static const char* values[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const card &c)
{
    out << values[c.v] << " of " << suits[c.s];
    return out;
}

void get_winner(const card (*hands)[num_players][2], const card (*mid_cards)[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << "Middle card " << i + 1 << ": " << (*mid_cards)[i] << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        std::cout << "Player " << i + 1 << "hand: " << (*hands)[i][0] << ", " << (*hands)[i][1] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    card hands[num_players][2];
    card mid_cards[5];
    // fill hands and mid_cards with card structs
    hands[0][0] = card {jack, hearts};
    hands[0][1] = card {nine, spades};
    hands[1][0] = card {ace, clubs};
    hands[1][1] = card {ace, hearts};
    hands[2][0] = card {three, diamonds};
    hands[2][1] = card {seven, spades};
    hands[3][0] = card {eight, diamonds};
    hands[3][1] = card {nine, clubs};
    mid_cards[0] = card {five, clubs};
    mid_cards[1] = card {king, hearts};
    mid_cards[2] = card {queen, spades};
    mid_cards[3] = card {two, clubs};
    mid_cards[4] = card {ace, hearts};
    get_winner(&hands, &mid_cards);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/OzWd9P)

Alternatively, pass the arrays by reference instead of pointer, eg:

```
#include <iostream>

enum suit {hearts, diamonds, spades, clubs};
enum value {two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace};

struct card 
{
    value v;
    suit s;
};
static const int num_players = 4;

static const char* suits[] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
static const char* values[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const card &c)
{
    out << values[c.v] << " of " << suits[c.s];
    return out;
}

void get_winner(const card (&hands)[num_players][2], const card (&mid_cards)[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << "Middle card " << i + 1 << ": " << mid_cards[i] << "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        std::cout << "Player " << i + 1 << "hand: " << hands[i][0] << ", " << hands[i][1] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    card hands[num_players][2];
    card mid_cards[5];
    // fill hands and mid_cards with card structs
    hands[0][0] = card {jack, hearts};
    hands[0][1] = card {nine, spades};
    hands[1][0] = card {ace, clubs};
    hands[1][1] = card {ace, hearts};
    hands[2][0] = card {three, diamonds};
    hands[2][1] = card {seven, spades};
    hands[3][0] = card {eight, diamonds};
    hands[3][1] = card {nine, clubs};
    mid_cards[0] = card {five, clubs};
    mid_cards[1] = card {king, hearts};
    mid_cards[2] = card {queen, spades};
    mid_cards[3] = card {two, clubs};
    mid_cards[4] = card {ace, hearts};
    get_winner(hands, mid_cards);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/jEbokV)

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any reason I should pass by reference instead of by pointer. It seems like passing by pointer is more common

Comment: @kjdfsjdsakafsjna "*It seems like passing by pointer is more common*" - in C it is (since references don't exist in C), but in C++ references are preferred over pointers, when it makes sense to use them. References tend to be less error-prone than pointers (ie, references can't be null, but pointers can). But either way, you still have to make sure you manage references correctly, for instance to avoid any issues with *dangling* references, just like with pointers.